# Filtering a list of object based on nested type

Tags: algorithm, scala, collections, iteration

Lets say I have a class as follows:

```
case class Person(
name:String,
age:Int,
dependents:List[Person]
)
```

Lets say I have the following four people:

```
val p1 = Person("Tom",50,List(p2,p4))
val p2 = Person("Bob",20,List(p3))
val p3 = Person("Jimmy",25,List(p4))
val p4 = Person("Harry",11,Nil)
```

My people list is val pList = List(p1,p2,p3,p4)

I want to filter this collection to get all the people who have an 11 year old dependent.

What is one way to do it?

The algorithm can be summed up as For each dependent(d) of each person(p) in pList, if age of dependant(d) is == 11, collect the person(p).

How do I express it in scala?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Take the list of persons, and use the filter method on it, checking if each dependent contains a person whose age is 11.

```
pList.filter(_.dependents.exists(_.age == 11))
```

This will only check 1 layer deep obviously, so in your example, it will return `Tom` and `Jimmy`, because they are the only `Persons` with a direct dependent who is 11 years old:

```
Person(
  Tom,
  50,
  List(Person(Bob,20,List(Person(Jimmy,25,List(Person(Harry,11,List()))))), Person(Harry,11,List()))
  )
Person(
  Jimmy,
  25,
  List(Person(Harry,11,List()))
  )
```

Alternatively you could make it a little more generic like so:

```
def dependentAged(age: Int)(person: Person) = person.dependents.exists(_.age == age)
val filtered = pList.filter(dependentAged(11))
```

Comment: I have to mention, that the latter fails when there are (wrongly) cycles in the object graph.

Comment: Hmm, could you fix/provide an example?

Comment: @ziggystar - It's hard to create cycles with immutable case classes.

Answer (score 4):

Your description of the algorithm translates very well to a [for comprehension](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/111) in scala.

> For each dependent(d) of each person(p) in pList, if age of
>   dependant(d) is == 11, collect the person(p)

We iterate through `pList` and create a new variable `person` at each iteration. If the dependents of the person meet the guard criteria, we `yield` that person from `pList`. i.e. `if person.dependents.exists(dependent => dependent.age == 11)`

With `for` and `yield`:

```
for(person <- pList if person.dependents.exists(dependent => dependent.age == 11)) yield person
```

This gives a list of two people:

```
List[Person] = List(
  Person(Tom,50,List(Person(Bob,20,List(Person(Jimmy,25,List(Person(Harry,11,List()))))),     
  Person(Harry,11,List()))), Person(Jimmy,25,List(Person(Harry,11,List())))
)
```

Comment: Just a query, as I am still learning Scala: this is translated to a map and filter under the hood isn't it.

Comment: Yep. Compiling with `-Xprint:typer` shows the for expression without the sugar `pList.withFilter(((person) => person.dependents.exists(((dependent) => dependent.age.$eq$eq(11))))).map(((person) => person))`